# DDD modelisation issue (entity accessing repository)

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am designing the model of the following business needs :

- The application must be able to register Users
- The steps of the User registration are :

  1. The user enters an email address and confirm
  2. A verification code is sent to the provided email address.
  3. The user must enter the correct verification code to continue
  4. Repeat steps 1-3 for a phone number with verification code by SMS (optional)
  5. The user then enters some personal information and confirm => the account is created
- After registration, the user can update his email address or mobile phone number, but must go through the same verification process (code sent which must be entered to confirm the modification)

I ended up with the following model :

- Verifiable (interface)
- User (entity)
- EmailAddress (value type, is a Verifiable)
- MobilePhoneNumber (value type, is a Verifiable)
- RandomCode (value type)
- VerificationCode (entity containing a Verifiable, a RandomCode and a generationDateTime)
- VerificationEmail (aggregate containing a VerificationCode, an EmailAddress and a Locale)
- VerificationSms (aggregate containing a VerificationCode, a MobilePhoneNumber and a Locale)

Then here come the questions !!

- Is it correct to have the Verifiable interface in order to have a VerificationCode instead of having EmailVerificationCode and SmsVerificationCode ? (Although it's not really a part of the ubiquitous language)
- As I must persist somewhere the tuple emailAddress/mobilePhoneNumber + randomCode + generationDateTime to be able to retrieve it for verification, is it ok to have a specific entity for this ?
- When the user wants to update his email address I was expecting to do something like :

  ```
  // In the application service
  User u = userRepository.findByUid(uid);
  u.updateEmailAddress(newEmailAddress, enteredCode);
  userRepository.save(u);

  // In the User class
  public void updateEmailAddress(EmailAddress newEmailAddress, String code) {
      // Here comes the direct repository access
      VerificationCode v = verificationCodeRepository.findByVerifiable(newEmailAddress);
      if (v != null && v.hasNotExpired() && v.equalsToCode(code)) {
          this.emailAddress = newEmailAddress;
          verificationCodeRepository.delete(v);
      }
      else {
          throw new IncorrectVerificationCodeException();
      }
  }
  ```

  but to prevent my entity accessing a repository I ended up with the following code :

  ```
  // In the application service
  User u = userRepository.findByUid(uid);
  VerificationCode v = verificationCodeRepository.findByVerifiable(newEmailAddress);
  if (v != null && v.hasNotExpired() && v.equalsToCode(code)) {
      verificationCodeRepository.delete(v);
      u.updateEmailAddress(newEmailAddress);
      userRepository.save(u);
  }
  else {
      throw new IncorrectVerificationCodeException();
  }

  // In the User class
  public void updateEmailAddress(EmailAddress newEmailAddress) {
      this.emailAddress = newEmailAddress;
  }
  ```

  But it looks like an anemic model and the business logic is now in the application layer...

I am really struggling to correctly design the model as this is my first DDD project, any advice, modelisation suggestion is welcomed...

Comment: What about this instead? Command issued -> Command verification interceptor -> Verification needed -> Proper verification request created, bound to original command -> Verification request sent -> Verification request fulfilled -> Command bound to verification issued (without re-triggered verification somehow). The commands are never reaching the ARs until the verification process is complete. The advantage I see is that the whole verification mechanism is abstracted away from the account management domain (could even be a supporting BC perhaps).

Comment: @plalx Could you please detail your solution in an answer ? With concrete pseudo-code it would help me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong passing a repository as an argument in your updateEmailAddress() method.

But there is a better alternative, a domain service:

Your domain service depends on the repository and encapsulates the logic bound to your verification. You then pass this service to the user entity which is in charge of calling the correct method.

Here is how it could looks like:

```
class EmailVerificationService {

    VerificationCodeRepository repository;

    boolean isCodeVerified(EmailAddress emailAddress, String code) {
        // do your things with the repository
        // return true or false
    }
}
```

Then in the user class:

```
class User {

    // ...

    public void updateEmailAddress(EmailVerificationService service, EmailAddress emailAddress, String code) {
        if (service.isCodeVerified(emailAddress, code)) {
            this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        } else {
            // throw business Exception ? 
        }
    }
}
```

In your application service, you inject the domain service and wire everything, catching the eventual exception and returning an error message to the user.

Comment: For a DDD newcomer, it is a bit counterintuitive to put the service as an argument. What are the benefits of this approach opposed to the User having a direct reference to the repository (or to the service) ? And what about my first two questions ? I don't know how to choose between abstraction and ubiquitous language...

Comment: The problem with User having a direct reference to the repository is the User becomes untestable, or difficultly testable, also when you instantiate that user you need to use Dependency Lookup each time your create a new object. It might be a question of choice, but I personally don't find it elegant.

About your first question, it is correct. Actually its true and false saying it does not belong to the ubiquitous language. It belongs to what we call a Generic Subdomain, and in that subdomain, it is part of the ubiquitous language.

Comment: About your second question you should check the work of Vaughn Vernon, and in particular the Enablement object contained as part of the User object:

https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_identityaccess/src/main/java/com/saasovation/identityaccess/domain/model/identity/User.java

And the InvitationDescriptor:

https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_identityaccess/src/main/java/com/saasovation/identityaccess/domain/model/identity/InvitationDescriptor.java

Comment: Now if I want to add a check of uniqueness about the email address. Another service ? Merge in the same service ? Rely on repository to fail for duplicate key ?

Comment: @Darnoj you can do whatever you like. For me this is dogmatism at this point.

Either you are pragmatic and go for the repository to fail on duplicate key, either you stick to the dogmatic vision and check in the service a key does not already exist. Results are the same, and covered by a domain test or application test.

Comment: Well, as it is a domain rule I think it should not be hidden in a database constraint... But if the UserRepository has methods like isEmailAlreadyUsed and isMobileAlreadyUsed, should it be called from application layer or from another domain service ? Knowing that I call this check in order to raise a BusinessException

Comment: Definitely from a domain service.

Keep the application layer thin, in charge of high level logging, security, and spanning transactions. All the business related logic, as your check of unicity belongs to domain.

Answer (score 1):

This is a suggestion of modeling, if you want to take it into account. Hope it could help you. I would model it this way:

**User (aggregate root entity)**

- id
- emailAddress (not null and unique)
- mobilePhoneNumber (optional)
- personalInfo
- enabled (a user is created disabled when the registration process starts, and it is enabled when the process ends successfully)

**VerificationCode (aggregate root entity) ===> it is associated to a user**

- id
- randomCode
- expirationDate
- userId
- smsOption (boolean) ===> if sms option is true, this verification code will be sent in a SMS to the user (otherwise it will be sent by email to the user)
- Static Factory meethods:

forSendingByEmail ==> creates an instance with smsOption false

forSendingBySMS ===> creates and instance with smsOption true

**Domain Service:** sendVerificationCodeToUser ( verificationCodeId ) ===> checks smsOption to send either an SMS or an email (to the mobilePhoneNumber/emailAddress of the associated userId)

**DomainEvent:** VerificationCodeWasCreated ===> it has the id of the verification code that has been created

- Raised by the VerificationCode constructor
- The listener will call the domain service: sendVerificationCodeToUser(verificationCodeWasCreated.verificationCodeId())

**THE REGISTRATION PROCESS (application service methods):**

**(1) The user enters an email address and confirm**

public void registerUser ( String email ):

- checks that doesn't exists any enabled user with the given email
- if exist a disable user with the email, delete it
- creates and persist a new disabled user with the email
- creates and persist a new verification code associated to the created user for sending by email

**(2) A verification code is sent to the provided email address** ===> it is done by the domain event listener

**(3) The user must enter the correct verification code to continue** ===> the user who was sent the email in step (1) has to enter the email again, and the code he received)

```
public boolean isARandomCodeCorrectForUserEmail ( String randomCode, String email ) {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    if (user==null) {
        return false;
    }
    VerificationCode vcode = verificationCodeRepository.findByRandomCodeAndUserId(randomCode,user.id());
    if ( vcode==null) {
        return false;
    }
    return vcode.hasNotExpired();
}
```

**(4) Repeat steps 1-3 for a phone number with verification code by SMS (optional)**

**(4.1) The user of step (3) enters mobile phone number (we know the user id):**

public void generateCodeForSendingBySmsToUser ( String mobilePhoneNumber, String userId ):

- update user of userId with the given mobilePhoneNumber
- creates and persist a new verification code associated to the user for sending by SMS

**(4.2) The event listener sends the SMS**

**(4.3) The user who was sent the SMS in step (4.2) has to enter the email of step (1) again, and the code he received by SMS** ===> isARandomCodeCorrectForUserEmail(randomCode,email)

**(5) The user then enters some personal information and confirm ===> the account is created** ===> what I do is enabling the user, since the user is already created, and we know the userId from step (3) or (4.3)

public void confirmRegistration ( PersonalInfo personalInfo, String userId ):

- update user of userId with the given personalInfo
- enables de the user

**THE EMAIL/MOBILEPHONENUMBER MODIFICATION PROCESS:**

It is similar to the registration, but the email/mobilePhoneNumber entered at the beginning must belongs to an existing enabled user, and at the end an update of the user is performed, instead of enabling.

**ENABLED/DISABLED USERS:**

Having enabled and disabled users, makes you taking it into account in authentication and authorization methods. If you don't want to or you're not allowed to have enabled/disabled users, you would have to model another aggregate that it would be UserCandidate or something like that, just with id, email and mobilePhoneNumber. And at the end of the process, create the real user with those values.